# finding specific files and data inside files

Tags: search

I am pretty new to Ubuntu I am trying to grasp concepts of finding specific files in directories and in another instance finding specific string or pattern of strings in files.
I have read various articles and found command grep and find.
Am I on the right track if not please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**grep** command is used to search text or searches the given file for lines containing a match to the given strings or words. By default, grep displays the matching lines.

Examples :

```
grep 'yourword' filename 
grep 'yourword' file1 file2 file3
grep 'string1 string2'  filename
cat otherfile | grep 'something'
command | grep 'something'
command option1 | grep 'data'
grep --color 'data' fileName
```

**Find** Command is one of the most important and much used command in Linux sytems. Find command used to search and locate list of files and directories based on conditions.

Examples :

Find all the files whose name is test.txt in a current working directory.

```
find . -name test.txt
```

Find all directories whose name is test in / directory.

```
find / -type d -name test
```

Find all the files whose name is test.txt and contains both capital and small letters in /home directory.

```
find /home -iname test.txt
```

More Help `man grep , man find`

Reference [Site](http://www.tecmint.com/35-practical-examples-of-linux-find-command/)

Comment: sir what is the semantic of using cat with grep?

Comment: cat data.txt | grep test , will display only test string from data.txt if its found

Comment: oh i see... that helped.

Comment: your are welcome my friend , any time

Comment: you should visit the reference site , its has pretty good examples

Answer (score 1):

To search for specific file inside directory,

```
locate filename
```

OR

```
find /path/to/search -iname 'filename'
```

To search for specific word in a file

```
grep text /path/to/the/file
```

Comment: will locate work for all directories inside a directory if a file is deep inside a directory for example.

Comment: `find /path/to/search -iname 'filename'` command does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` and `grep` command in various ways :

**find**

- To find a file e.g. `demo.tx`t in current directory use:
  `find . -name demo.txt`   where `.` represent current directory. You can change it according to your need.
- To find same file in home ignoring case :

  `find ~/ -iname demo.txt` where `~/` represent your home directory.
- To find directory in  use:

  `find . -type d -name <directory_name>`
- Finding all empty file

  `find . -type f -empty`
- Finding all empty directory

  `find . -type d -empty`
- Finding all file greater than 100 MB

  `find / -size +100M`

for more see `man find`

**grep**

- Search for the given string in a  file

  `grep "<string>" <filename>`
- searching for given string in multiple files

  `grep "<string>" <file_pattern>`
- Case insensitive search for the given string in a  file

  `grep -i "string" <file_name>`

for more see `man grep`

Answer (score 1):

The most useful version of `grep` might be `grep -r`. **-r** doesn't just search the specified directory: it *recursively* searches down through all the child folders, so if you don't know where you put a file, grep will find it for you.